# laravel5 controller issue. Undefined variable: filename

Tags: laravel, variables, laravel-5, controller, undefined

I want to upload a blogger's profile image but I get an error:

> Undefined variable: file_name.

I think it is a controller issue. I don't know why the variable is not defined, though I declared the same variable name.
I restarted the server but it did not work.

So please help me out.

**BloggerController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request, User $user_id)
{
    $user_id = DB::table('users')->where('id', $user_id)->get();

    if ($request->hasfile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file_name = time() . '.' . $ext;
        $file->move('bloggers/', $file_name);
    }

    $blog = Blog::create(
        ['user_id' => $user_id],
        [
            'image'        => $file_name,
            'introduction' => $request->introduction,
        ]
    );

    return redirect(route('blogger'));
}
```

I also changed the store method.

```
if ($request->hasfile('image')) {
    $file_name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $request->file('image')->storeAs('bloggers/', $file_name);
}
```

My migration

```
Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('bloggers');
    $table->string('image');
    $table->string('introduction');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

[image: error image]

Comment: are you sure that it passes on this condition $request->hasfile('image') ? Yes it will be undefined because it does not passed in your condition.

Comment: Can a `Blog` be created without an image??

Comment: @Rwd No image is required...

Comment: In that case I would recommend looking at https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation so that you don't need to check if the image exists in the code.

Comment: @Rwd Yes, I will do it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure that your variable $fillename is available then change your code to this

```
if($request->hasfile('image')){
      $file = $request->file('image');
      $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $filename = time().'.'.$ext;
      $file->move('bloggers/', $filename);

      $blog = Blog::create(
            ['user_id' => $user_id],
            [
                'image'=>$filename,
                'introduction' => $request->introduction,
            ]
        );
}
```

Comment: But I have a next error when I go to the page, just link is showed up...

Comment: sorry, my new error is about the route, so I will try to fix myself! Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you must return file address and name in uploader

```
public function store(Request $request, User $user_id){

        $user_id = DB::table('users')->where('id', $user_id)->get();
        if($request->hasfile('image')){
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file_name = time().'.'.$ext;
            $file->move('bloggers/', $file_name);
        }


        $blog = Blog::create(
            ['user_id' => $user_id],
            [
                'image'=>"/bloggers/".$file_name,
                'introduction' => $request->introduction,
            ]
        );
        return redirect(route('blogger'));
    }
```

i think its work

Comment: How will this prevent `$file_name` from being undefined?

Answer (score 0):

You tried accessing the variable out of scope. Make it an external variable by declaring it out of the if function as I show below on line 2 of the code.
...

```
public function store(Request $request, User $user_id){
        $file_name="";
        $user_id = DB::table('users')->where('id', $user_id)->get();
        if($request->hasfile('image')){
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file_name = time().'.'.$ext;
            $file->move('bloggers/', $file_name);
        }


        $blog = Blog::create(
            ['user_id' => $user_id],
            [
                'image'=>"/bloggers/".$file_name,
                'introduction' => $request->introduction,
            ]
        );
        return redirect(route('blogger'));
    }
```

...

Comment: Sorry but I got a new error, SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:.

Comment: But thnk you for your help !